# Dynamic project paths in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have a solution which loads projects from other repositories in TFS. Lets say I want to add Project A to my solution. Project A has multiple versions and they are present at repositories ProjectA/1.0, ProjectA/2.0 etc.

Is there a way I can specify that I want version 2.0 for Project A and it will automatically open the appropriate version. I don't want to create environment variables or manually change the project paths in the sln file.

Comment: does setting environment variable in a build action script count?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken build action scripts have to be written for a project? I would prefer something that was only dependent on the solution.

Comment: Do you have any form of source control?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the solution would be to independently store different projects in different source control repositories, then dynamically interlink to the right versions where needed.

Comment: You might be right. I'm using TFS and that is the exact problem I'm facing.

Comment: @JamesThorpe how does one dynamically interlink to the right versions?

Comment: In TFS?  No idea - never used it!  You might want to [edit] your question to talk about your underlying problem though, rather than your attempt to get around it, along with tagging TFS etc - you should get better answers that way.

Comment: We are using [release branches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx) to achieve this. Every project (we are actually using solutions) has to have one or more release branches referenced in other solutions. Main solutions also has them. Therefore getting e.g. 1.0 version will load only those libraries what were referenced by it. If you need 2.0 you just get it (together with its referenced libraries). No need to use variable, it will be different folder for different version anyway.

Comment: If project A is used to create packages, you can also consider using a package manager such as NuGet to publish your packages: https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package